# tbb concurrent hashmap to implement dictionary ADT

Tags: c++, concurrency, hashmap, tbb

I'm trying to implement a dictionary ADT using TBB's concurrent hashmap. I'm having problems with the sequential version. So I guess something is wrong with the way I use the map functions.
`gdb` says the code hangs in a call to `erase(key)` which in turn calls a `lock` routine. Smells like a deadlock. Here is the **corrected** code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include "tbb/concurrent_hash_map.h"
using namespace tbb;
using namespace std;

typedef concurrent_hash_map<unsigned long,bool> tbbMap;
tbbMap map;

int findPercent;
int insertPercent;
int deletePercent;
unsigned long keyRange;
unsigned int lseed;

bool search(unsigned long key)
{
    if(map.count(key))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

bool insert(unsigned long key)
{
    if(map.insert(std::make_pair(key,true)))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return(false);
    }
}

bool remove(unsigned long key)
{
    if(map.erase(key))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return(false);
    }
}

void operateOnDictionary()
{
    int chooseOperation;
    unsigned long key;
    int count=0;
    while(count<10)
    {
        chooseOperation = rand_r(&lseed)%100; 
        key = rand_r(&lseed)%keyRange + 1;
        if(chooseOperation < findPercent)
        {
            search(key);
        }
        else if (chooseOperation < insertPercent)
        {
            insert(key);
        }
        else
        {
            remove(key);
        }
        count++;
    }
    printf("done\n");
    return;
}

int main()
{
    findPercent = 10;
    insertPercent= findPercent + 45;
    deletePercent = insertPercent + 45;
    keyRange = 5;
    lseed = 0;
    operateOnDictionary();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly, it is wrong usage of the accessor. It is supposed to be scoped, [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) object, not a global one.

What actually happens is `find()` or `insert()` acquires the lock in the accessor and it is not released since the accessor is not destructed and does not release the lock. Then, `erase()` tries to acquire the same lock and hags since it is acquired already.

BTW, consider using `count()` if you need just to check if the key exists and don't need to read anything from it. Also don't use `insert(with_accessor,key)` if you don't plan to access the element after insertion, use `insert( std::make_pair(key, value) )` which does not use accessor.

Dealing with accessors implies certain runtime overhead since it is per-element lock in the essence. E.g. it would not be fair to compare `concurrent_unordered_map` which has no accessors and `concurrent_hash_map` with accessors.

Comment: Thanks :) I randomly search, insert or delete a key as in a dictionary ADT. So there is a chance that an element may be accessed multiple times. For simplicity I do not care about the value. All I care is if a key exist `search` returns `true`, `insert` returns `false` and delete returns `true`

Comment: @arunmoezhi, welcome, check out also `count_strings` example from TBB

Comment: Yes I checked that example. It uses an accessor and calls `insert()` and `size()` functions. How do I call `find()` without an accessor?

Comment: you cannot access the data without the accessor (in public interface :) ). But you can use `count()` if you don't need to. Please pay attention to `const_accessor` as well if you don't need to write to the data

Comment: oh. I undestand now. In this case, as find does not do anything with the data I should use `const_accessor`. It worked!!

Comment: If it really does not do anything with the data, use count, it is faster

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71290/discussion-between-arunmoezhi-and-anton).